# Add an Array to an JSON Object

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my API im receiving a JSON with 2 arrays, one Employees and another with Managers, the goal is to add the Managers to each Employee, knowing that the 1st index of the managers corresponds to the 1st index of the employees and so on:

This is an example of the request to the API

```
{
"employees" : [ {
    "code" : "111111",
    "name" : "Zé"
},
{
    "code" : "222222",
    "name" : "João"
},
{
    "code" : "444444",
    "name" : "António"
}],
"managers" : [
    [
        {
            "name": "vitor",
            "level" : "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Antonio",
            "level" : "2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "Jose",
            "level" : "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ines",
            "level" : "2"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "Luis",
            "level" : "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ana",
            "level" : "2"
        }
    ]
]
```

}

and my goal is to get something like this:

```
[
    {
        "code": "111111",
        "name": "Zé",
        "managers": [
            {
                "name": "vitor",
                "level": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Antonio",
                "level": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "222222",
        "name": "João",
        "managers": [
            {
                "name": "Jose",
                "level": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Ines",
                "level": "2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "code": "444444",
        "name": "António",
        "managers": [
            {
                "name": "Jose",
                "level": "1"
            },
            {
                "name": "Ines",
                "level": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I already tried some things but i can't get the expected result :(
Hope you can help me!! Thanks

Comment: 1 employee can have all managers? I don't see any related data between employees and managers.

Comment: How do employees and managers relate? There doesn't seem to be a logic around who goes with who

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: 3rd entry in your expected output is confusing.. is it copy-paste error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function associate_employee_managers({ employees, managers }) {
    return employees && employees.length
        && employees
            .map((emp, index) => {
                return {
                    ...emp,
                    ["managers"]: managers && managers[index] || []
                };
            }) || {};
}
```

---

### ***Considerations***

> There is 1-1 correspondence(based on index) between entries inside `employees` array and `managers` array

---

### Illustration

```js
function associate_employee_managers({
  employees,
  managers
}) {
  return employees && employees.length &&
    employees
    .map((emp, index) => {
      return {
        ...emp,
        ["managers"]: managers && managers[index] || []
      };
    }) || {};
}

const jsonResponse = {
  "employees": [{
      "code": "111111",
      "name": "Zé"
    },
    {
      "code": "222222",
      "name": "João"
    },
    {
      "code": "444444",
      "name": "António"
    }
  ],
  "managers": [
    [{
        "name": "vitor",
        "level": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Antonio",
        "level": "2"
      }
    ],
    [{
        "name": "Jose",
        "level": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ines",
        "level": "2"
      }
    ],
    [{
        "name": "Luis",
        "level": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Ana",
        "level": "2"
      }
    ]
  ]
}

console.log(associate_employee_managers(jsonResponse));
```

---

### ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***